# How to define a macro in a makefile for enabling a feature in a C header?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I want to define a macro in one of the header files. Can I set it through a makefile?

For example, I want to set a macro "PAGING_ON" which I want to be a preprocessor macro for source files. (The project is in C.) Is it possible to set it through the Makefile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the compilers I know about have this option; for example, you can use compilation flag `-D` in gcc (`-DPAGING_ON`)

For Visual C (and variants) it is [`/D`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: `/D`. You can see more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Usually, you need to adjust a macro, CFLAGS, but simply setting CFLAGS is often not the best way to do it.  You have to look at how the rules for the makefiles are built up.  The compilation rule typically uses something like `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $*`, but the macro CFLAGS may be built up from a number of other macros.